# hiding method from certain layers in project

Tags: asp.net

I was looking through an old project and wanted to see if anyone had a suggestion on how to hide certain methods from being called by various layers.  This was a 3 tier project, webapplication -> web service -> database

In the application there is a User object for example.  When a User was being updated, the webapplication would create a User object and pass it to the webservice.  The webservice would use the DataAccessLayer to save the User object to the database.  After looking at this I was wondering if instead I should have made a Save method in the User class.  This way the service and simply call the Save on the User object which would trigger the db update.

However doing it this way would expose the Save to be called from the webapplication as well, correct?  Since the webapplication also has access to the same User object.

Is there anyway around this, or is it better to avoid this altogether?

Comment: Ideally, you want to use interfaces to pass objects between layers.  That way if there is a `DataLayerUser` class that the DAL uses, instead of of the `User` object, it only needs to meet the contract of the interface.  And in this practice, your `DataLayerUser` may have a `Save` method, that only the DAL layer can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separation of concerns by keepeing the `User` object as object that only holds data with no logic in it. you better keep it separated for the following reasons:

1. As you stated, it is a bad practice since the Save' functionality will be exposed to other places/classes where it is irrelevant for them (This is an important for programming generally).
2. Modifying the service layer - I guess you are using WCF web service as you can transfer a `.NET` object (c#/VB) to the service via SOAP. If you put the saving logic in the 'User' object, you can't replace it another webservice that receives a simple textual data structures like `JSON` or `XML` or simply doesn't support `.NET` objects.
3. Modifying the data storage layer - If you want, for example, to store the data inside a different place like other database such as MongoDB, RavenDB, Redis or what ever you want, you will have to reimplement each class that responsible for updating the data. This is also relevant for **Unit Testing and Mocking**, making them more complicated to interrogate.